# Core Data crash on relationship save

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a core data app that I'm trying to add a new object to an entity with a relationship. Something is going wrong with accessing that relationship entity that is causing the app to crash on **save**

The addition is happening within a sheet.

Save action:

```
-(IBAction)addNewRepair:(id)sender {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Equipment"  inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];

    [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(serial like %@)",[[serialPopUp selectedItem] title]]];

    fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    Equipment *equipmentObject = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    Repairs *newRepair = (Repairs*)[NSEntityDescription
                                    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Repairs"
                                    inManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]];

    [newRepair setValue:invoiceNumberTextFeild.stringValue forKeyPath:@"invoiceNumber"];
    [newRepair setValue:warrentyTextField.stringValue forKeyPath:@"warrantyDate"];
    [newRepair setValue:repairReasonTextField.stringValue forKeyPath:@"repairDetails"];
    [newRepair setValue:serviceProvidedTextField.stringValue forKeyPath:@"serviceSummary"];
    [newRepair setValue:serviceDateTextField.stringValue forKeyPath:@"repairDate"];
    [equipmentObject addRepairsObject:(Repairs *)newRepair];

    if (![[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]  save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSLog((@"Repair Successfully added"));
    [NSApp endSheet:self.sheet];
    [self.sheet close];
}
```

fetch method:

```
-(void)fetchItems {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Equipment"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Equipment" inManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]];

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"item"]];

    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

    itemDictionaries = [[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    NSLog(@"item: %@", itemDictionaries);

    [nameController setContent:itemDictionaries];
    self.itemSelection = [itemDictionaries firstObject];

    self.predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item == %@", [[nameController selection] valueForKeyPath:@"item"]];
}
```

What could possibly be going wrong with this method?

My equipment.h file implements a custom accessor:

```
- (void)addRepairsObject:(Repairs *)value;
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Repairs"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey: @"Repairs"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Repairs"];
}
```

the error I get is:

> 2014-08-06 12:41:50.805 CNSplitView_Example[64803:4407] -[Equipment
>   copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080002c0a10

Even though `equipment.h' lists`repairs` as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *repairs;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? From what I am reading, this is a common problem (almost always on IOS, not OS X apps) but without a widely documented solution.

I have also tried this:

```
NSMutableSet *newRepairObject = [NSMutableSet setWithObject:equipmentObject];
    equipmentObject.repairs = newRepairObject;
```

same error.

## Edit:

Found out that `NSManagedObjects` do NOT conform to `NSCopying` protocol. (So why is error producing copyWithZone on that entity?)

Comment: Does the `Equipment` class adopt `NSCopying` protocol?  The error message suggests to me that the app expects it to.

Comment: if I try to implement nscopying, I still get the same error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000002bb660 with userInfo (null)"

Comment: Also, from what I'm reading, NSManagedObjects don't conform to NSCopying anyuway

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the addRepairsObject: method. You are using the property accessor setPrimitiveValue: when you should be using the one-to-many relationship accessors. The Core Data Programming Guide gives an example in the section [Managed Object Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154)

```
@dynamic employees;


- (void)addEmployeesObject:(Employee *)value {

    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
          withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
          usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveEmployees] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"employees"
          withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
          usingObjects:changedObjects];
}
```

Substitute 'repairs' for 'employees' and you should be fine. The NSCopying errors are red herrings: in Core Data, quite a lot of stuff happens underwater and a crash there can send some strange debris floating upwards, obscuring the real problem.